# When you manually update a YAML file for a node in GKE UI, does it affect the node?

Tags: cloud, google-kubernetes-engine

scenario for example:

1. open Google cloud -> clusters -> choose cluster ->  nodes
2. choose specific node details
3. YAML -> Edit
4. remove: cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: default-pool
5. save
6. getting: Resource has been updated

Could this affect the node pool? If so, why, and what would be the impact of editing this YAML if not

[image]

[image]

cluster Version:    1.25.11-gke.1700

Comment: Hey Adi, I tried to reproduce your steps in a zonal GKE cluster running version 1.27.3-gke.100 but could not follow the same steps (Step 3 in specific), would you mind to confirm your GKE cluster type, version and if possible add screenshots?

Comment: Hi.. I just edited and added screenshot. cluster Version: 1.25.11-gke.1700, Location type Zonal (I am not sure what do you mean by cluster type?)

Answer (score 1):

When you edit the YAML configuration of the node via UI, it will affect the node pool on which the node belongs. The label is used to identify the node pool where the node resides so removing it will disassociate that one which makes it an orphan. Settings for Auto Scaling and GKE management such as auto-updates and upgrades would be affected as well. Attached is a documentation for managing nodes for additional reference.[1]

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/